# Javascript - share just one event listener and also have promise like behavior

Tags: javascript, css

I have a animation that runs right before a stack of functions. I need the functions to run only after the animation is complete....a promise like behavior. I have a eventlistener for this. But the issue is, for efficiency I only want to have one event listener that all the `page` functions can use.

Is this possible to achieve with a single event listener? and how can I implement a promise like behavior when the event listener fires?

```
var mainPanelContent = document.getElementById('mainPanelContent');
mainPanelContent.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function (eve) {
  console.log('anamation is done');
});
```

---

```
page('/', function (event) {
  if (currentPage !== 0) {
    //ON 'webkitAnimationEnd' do the below code
    clickOnHome();
    pageName = elementList[currentPage].localName;
    toggleAllButActivePage(pageName);
    findContentAndShow('home');
  }
});

page('/portfolio', function () {
  if (currentPage !=1) {
    //ON 'webkitAnimationEnd' do the below code
    toggleAllButActivePage('portfolio-page');
    findContentAndShow('portfolio-page');
    clickOnPage('rgb(68, 89, 99)');
  }
});
page('/resume', function () {
  if (currentPage !=2) {
    //ON 'webkitAnimationEnd' do the below code
    toggleAllButActivePage('resume-page');
    findContentAndShow('resume-page');
    clickOnPage('#424242');
  });
```

**Solution**:

Thank you for your suggestions, I ended up going with this to keep the code lighter, otherwise I would have to remove the eventlistener after every promise wrap:

```
var afterSlideDown = { runStack: function() {} }

mainPanelContent.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function (animationEvent) {
  if (animationEvent.animationName === "slide-down") {
    afterSlideDown.runStack();
    mainPanelContent.classList.remove('slide-down-now')
  }
});
```

---

```
function portfolio() {
  toggleAllButActivePage('portfolio-page');
  findContentAndShow('portfolio-page');
  clickOnPage('rgb(68, 89, 99)');
}

page('/portfolio', function () {
  if (currentPage !=1) {
    afterSlideDown.runStack = portfolio;
    mainPanelContent.classList.add('slide-down-now');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help?

```
var mainPanelContent = document.getElementById('mainPanelContent');

function addCustomEventListener()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        mainPanelContent.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function (eve) {

          resolve(true);

          // you can come up with some logic to do a reject() ;-)

        });

    }); 
}

addCustomEventListener().then(function(){

     // should be called when promise is resolved
     console.log('anamation is done');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Event listener can work, it'd be just as if you were using callbacks. You can do this for a promise:

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve){
    function handler(e){
        //just one time
        mainPanelContent.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', handler);
        resolve(e);
    }
    var mainPanelContent = document.getElementById('mainPanelContent');
    //probs best to do animation here?
    mainPanelContent.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', handler);
});
p.then(function(e){
   //animationEnded here:
   //e = event data from the animationEnd handler.
});
```